# Return reference to value from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, reference, ienumerable

I'm newbie in c#, so question might be a stupid a little.

I want to iterate over collection and change it values in place (return reference to value).

Code i want to look looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> Iterate(int[] values)
{
    foreach (int value in values) { yield return value; }
}

void some() 
{
    int[] collection = new int[] {1,2,3};
    foreach (int elem in Iterate(collection)) {
        elem = elem*2;
    }
// collection is now a {2,4,6}

}
```

So what the easiest way to do this? Thanks.

UPD. The real problem is much more difficult ofc. This is just example shows i wanna use "reference to integer" or smth.

I just want closer analogue of this C++ code in C#:

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
for (auto& value: a) { value*=2; }
```

Comment: With a simple `for` loop over a `int[]` object. You're really overthinking it.

Comment: Real problem is more difficult of course.

Comment: then you need to tell us real problem!

Comment: This is complex iterate over many collections with many rules. I want to hide logic of iterating in one place and reading/writing in another.

Comment: The answer to this somewhat similar question might be applicable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918535/pointing-to-array-element/13918878#13918878

Comment: C# is not C++. Use an indexed `for` loop to edit the array in place, or use a projection to map it to another sequence.

Comment: @Selman22 In my opinion the OPs question is sufficient, no need for the "real problem". I just ran into the same problem: I have three big loops which are doing 90% the same. The only difference is at which elements of a two dimensional array they work (Sudoku solver that looks at rows, columns and sub-matrix). If I could get an Enumerator I could reuse the same loop and just throw in another Enumerator.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since the last update. Starting with C# 7.3, it is possible to use ref locals in foreach. Combined with the ref returns from property getters, it allows one to write a code like follows:

```
    void some() 
    {
        int[] collection = new int[] {1,2,3};
        foreach (ref int elem in collection.AsSpan()) 
            elem = elem*2;
    }
```

The `.AsSpan()` call is necessary because default enumerator for the T[] array does have plain T as the Current property return type.
Enumerator in the Span type does use `ref T Current {get;}` instead, thus allowing direct modification of the collection as the topic starter asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Use the powerful Linq functions.

```
int[] collection = new int[] {1,2,3}
var modified = collection.Select(i => i * 2).ToArray();
```

You can also use a method (called functions in c++) to hide more complex transformations.

```
int Transform(int input)
{
    return input * 2;
}

void Later()
{
    collection.Select(Transform);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple answer to your question: that's not possible.

Let's inspect how does this `foreach (var item in enumerable)` work behind the scenes.

When you state `foreach (var item in enumerable) item.DoWork();`, .NET compiler translates this to:

```
var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
try 
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
    {
        var current = enumerator.Current;
        current.DoWork();
    }
}
finally 
{
    enumerator.Dispose();
}
```

There is one important thing in this. The created enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and the next call to `MoveNext()` throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

So you just cannot modify your `IEnumerable` while fetching it via a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

use a for:

```
for(int i=0;i<collection.Length;i++)
{
  collection[i]=collection[i]*2;
}
```

Comment: This code shows needed result but not solve the problem.

Comment: could you explain what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ for-auto-ref syntax appeals to me, too, since (at least for the purpose of in-place mutation of lists of value-type objects) it's more expressive than a for-index loop in C#. However, you can still get a similar expressiveness in safe C# with a "helper" method that hides the bookkeeping. For example:

```
static void For<T>(IList<T> a, Func<T, T> f)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < a.Count; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = f(a[i]);
    }
}

// Usage:
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 }; // "a" can be any type that implements IList<T>
For(a, value => value * 2);
```

If you have **measured** this to be a hotspot in your code, you might want to define an analogous overload specifically for arrays, to allow better optimization by the compiler and/or runtime. For example:

```
// About 65% faster than with IList<T> (according to a rough benchmark on .NET Framework 4.8)
static void For<T>(T[] a, ForBody<T> f)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
    {
        f(ref a[i]);
    }
}

delegate void ForBody<T>(ref T value);

// Usage:
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 }; // "a" has to be an array
For(a, (ref int value) => value *= 2);
```

Finally, if performance is truly critical at the callsites of this method, you should replace the use of this method with an actual `for` statement, as the delegate invocation adds non-trivial overhead. In my benchmarking, using a `for` statement instead of this method was about 30% faster.

> This answer used to have two pointer-based options. One was generic using C# 7.3's `unmanaged` type constraint, and the other was non-generic. Compared to the method above using a generic array in safe code (with a delegate operating on `ref T`), the former was about 5% slower and the latter was less than 1% faster. Safe code FTW!